# I have been working with azure web app and want to use common data service as database

Tags: c#, azure

I am developing a web app using microsoft azure service. I am to use common data service as database for the app. There is a tutorial provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/entity-reference/cds-sdk-get-started).

But while going through the tutorial, when I reach the Application Registration section, I am unable to select common data service as api. The section of tutorial is listed below:

> 4. Set up the required permissions for connecting to the Common Data Service:
>
>    a. Click **Required permissions** to open a new pane.
>
>    b. Click **Add**.
>
>    c. Navigate to **Select an API**.
>
>    d. Search for and select **Common Data Service**, and then
>      click **Select**. If you can't find this service, see "Required
>      permissions service isn't found" in the "Troubleshooting" section,
>      later in this topic.
>
>    e. Select all the entries under **Delegated permissions**, and then click **Select**.
>
>    f. Click **Done** to complete the setup of permissions for this service.
>
>    g. Repeat the preceding steps for **Windows Azure Service Management API**.

Comment: Did you read through the `Required permissions services isn't found` section as suggested by the page you quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unable to select common data service as api

It seems that you can not find/select **Common Data Service** and **Windows Azure Service Management API** when you set up the required permissions.

[image]

If you see ["Required permissions service isn't found" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/entity-reference/cds-sdk-get-started#required-permissions-service-isnt-found), you can find that we can directly modify the application's JSON manifest and add the following entries under the JSON array that is named **requiredResourceAccess**.

```
{
    "resourceAppId": "82f77645-8a66-4745-bcdf-9706824f9ad0",
    "resourceAccess": [
    {
        "id": "4ae1b148-ab4d-496d-8183-9292090fcca4",
        "type": "Scope"
    }
    ]
},
{
    "resourceAppId": "797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013",
    "resourceAccess": [
    {
        "id": "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033",
        "type": "Scope"
    }
    ]
}
```

After modify the application's JSON manifest, you should find Common Data Service and Windows Azure Service Management API are added.

[image]